# Scraping data from interactive open ticket(events) map

Tags: python, maps, screen-scraping

i would like to scraping data by python from the interactive open ticket(events) map https://patras.sense.city/. Is it possible? I've tried various options using selenium, but being a newbie, everything fails, even trying to scroll down to the https://patras.sense.city/issues page and click the "Load More" button (Φόρτωση περισσοτέρων in greek language) at the bottom of the page.
Thanks

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.